# Sorting Ember ArrayController when iterating the model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an ArrayController (documents) which displays a list of ObjectsControllers (document) for its content.

My ArrayController template (Documents):

```
{{#each document in model}}
   {{render "document" document}}
{{/each}}
```

The issue I am facing is that the "sortProperties" and "sortAscending" properties on the ArrayController are no longer having any effect. I assume this is because I am looping "model". If I loop "each document in controller", the document ObjectControllers dont seem to get the model assigned to them as a call to .model then throws an undefined error. Should I be looping "controller" or "model"? If the answer is model, how can I sort it and if the answer is controller, how can I get the model set on each controller?

Comment: Does the `arrangedContent` property, rather than `model` work? By default, `model` is an alias for `content`, and `arrangedContent` is the ordered property for it.

Comment: @DRobinson Thanks, using `arrangedContent` gave me what I needed - the sorted array and each controller also got its model. If you provide your comment as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than modifying the base model, the sorted collection is exposed as `arrangedContent`.

To explain why it's `arrangedContent` rather than `arrangedModel`, in Ember's [ControllerMixin](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/controller.js#L57) `content` is defined as an alias for `model`, but it used to be the [other way around](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/7cc694ef8c32f0dba429962f29cdbd9203d223dd/packages/ember-runtime/lib/controllers/controller.js#L54).

Answer (score 0):

You may have to set the `itemController` property on your ArrayController (Documents).

See here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.ArrayController.html

Edit: Also, you had it right the first time with {{#each document in controller}}. Doing it straight from the model will ignore configuration in your controller, which includes sorting rules you may have.

Comment: It is set but has no effect.

Comment: But if I loop controller, the model does not get assigned to the individual ObjectControllers. The template displays the model values, but calling .model on an ObjectController results in an undefined error

Comment: Whenever you're accessing properties of an object such as your controller, you need to use .get and .set methods provided by Ember. Try `this.get('model')`, does that work?

Comment: If you are trying to trigger an action with the model, try passing it from the template, e.g. {{action 'save' this}} instead of {{action 'save'}} and then trying to access the model from the controller.